# Eclipse: How can I install an older plugin version from an update site?

Tags: eclipse, scala, eclipse-plugin, scala-ide

I want to determine if downgrading one of my Eclipse plugins to the previous version fixes the problem I have.  I was wondering if there is a general method using the plugin's Eclipse update site that I can use Eclipse's install GUI to install an older version of the plugin.

If it matters, the tool of interest is the Scala-IDE at this update site:
http://download.scala-ide.org/releases-28/2.0.0-beta

What I want is the previous build of the 2.0.0-beta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mirco Dotta answered this for me on the [Scala IDE Forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-ide-user/HRhp6W4UROM/njMIYYGrrYIJ).

If the previous plugin version had been installed in the past, and if the update site maintains older releases of the plugin, it should be possible to revert to a previous version you have installed by performing the following:

1. Uninstall the current plugin version (Eclipse -> About -> Installation Details -> Installed Software)
2. Re-install a previous version using the "Installation History" (Eclipse -> About -> Installation Details -> Installed History).

Note that in the case of the plugin I'm using, the update site does not maintain older versions, so this technique wouldn't help.

Comment: Released betas (beta10 or higher) are now available here for Scala 2.9 http://download.scala-ide.org/builds/beta-29-2.0.0/ and here for Scala 2.8 http://download.scala-ide.org/builds/beta-28-2.0.0/

Answer (score 7):

To downgrade Scala IDE, what I did was first *uninstall* [[1](http://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1000546?comment=21766032)] the current Scala plugin, and the reinstall the desired older version.

**Special note**: when reinstalling the older version, there's an [annoying bug you have to sidestep](http://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1000546?comment=21766032). As per Iulian Dragos' last comment on that ticket, **make sure you disable 'Contact all update sites during install to find required software' when installing the older version**. After this, I encountered a bug about an illegal charset name for a file that no longer existed: `/Applications/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/3801/1/.cp/lib:misc/scala-dev/plugins`. The bug report you linked in the comments shows the solution: launch Eclipse with `eclipse -clean`. I got another error related to `-Xpluginsdir`, but this was fixed by cleaning and rebuilding the project.

[[1](http://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1000546?comment=21766032)] To uninstall the current plugin, you can go to `[Help Menu] -> [Install new software...] -> [What is already installed]`. Then select three items `JDT Weaving`, `Scala IDE for Eclipse`, `Scala IDE for Eclipse Source` and click uninstall.

*Edit*: I guess this doesn't answer your question about *where to find* an update site with the previous version. I couldn't find previous betas on the website. Maybe you'll have to ask on the [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/scala-ide-user).

Comment: Do you mean this error that I too received?  ` 
illegal charset name 'C:\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\820\1\.cp\lib:misc\scala-devel\plugins`  I posted a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/treeshaker/issues/detail?id=6) on the treeshaker site, since I thought it might be treeshaker related.  I guess I should also submit it to Scala-IDE.

Comment: Yes, this one! Please post a bug on Scala IDE. Today, in discussion of a separate bug, Iulian Dragos mentioned he has not seen the charset error yet.

Comment: Your bug report link was useful: launching Eclipse with `eclipse -clean` fixed the problem for me. (I also had to clean and rebuild my project to fix an error associated with `-Xpluginsdir`).

Comment: These bugs now seem to be fixed in wip-experiment trunk. Scala IDE is now really solid for me, many thanks to the authors.